# Finishing a proof for commuting matrices $A,B$ implies $p(A)=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ and there exists $B$ such that $AB=BA$, then there exists a polynomial $p(t)$ with degree at most $n-1$ such that $p(A)=B$.

I have an argument, and I'm pretty sure it's almost complete, but it does not use the fact that $A$ and $B$ commute.

Proof: Let $B$ have eigenvalues $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$ (not necessarily distinct). Let $\vec{x_i}$ be the distinct eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Since $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are distinct, there exists a polynomial $p(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_it^i$ such that $p(\lambda_i)=\beta_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
p(A)\vec{x_i}&=a_0A^0\vec{x_i}+a_1A^1\vec{x_i}+\cdots+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}\vec{x_i}
\\&=a_0\lambda_i^0\vec{x_i}+a_1\lambda_i^1\vec{x_i}+\cdots+a_{n-1}\lambda_i^{n-1}\vec{x_i}
\\&=(a_0\lambda_i^0+a_1\lambda_i^1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\lambda_i^{n-1})\vec{x_i}
\\&=p(\lambda_i)\vec{x_i}
\\&=\beta_i\vec{x_i}
\end{align*}

Therefore, each $\beta_i$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$. So $B$ and $p(A)$ have the same eigenvalues.

I have that $p(A)$ and $B$ are similar, but not that they are equal. How do I go about finish this proof?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implicitely use the fact that $A$ and $B$ commute, since you use the fact that they are diagonalizable in the same base $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. It is for this reason that you can write $p(A)(x_i)=p(\lambda_i)(x_i)=\beta_ix_i=B(x_i)$ since you know that $x_i$ is an eigenvector of $B$. The fact that the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct implies that $B$ is diagonalizable in the same base than $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that $A$ and $B$ not necessarily have the same eigenvectors (if they don't commute). But if they commute, you can choose a base, such that $A$ and $B$ both have JNF in that base (hence also have the same eigenvectors).